# How to use Actionmailer4 without rails

Tags: ruby, actionmailer

I have used actionmailer 2.3 without rails and when tried the same code with 4.0 components ruby code that use actionmailer4 is not working. I have the solution now that works and I am going to respond in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'action_mailer'

    ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
       :enable_starttls_auto => :true,
       :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
       :port => 587,
       :domain => "xxxx.com",
       :authentication => :plain,
       :user_name => "aaaa@xxxx.com",
       :password => "ppppp"
    }

    ActionMailer::Base.view_paths= File.dirname(__FILE__)

    class TEST_CLASS_email < ActionMailer::Base
      default( {from: "aaaa@xxxx.com"} )

      def sendemail(s_email)
        @var = 'TESTING VARIABLE PASSING TO VIEW'
        mail(
          to: "bbbb.cccc@dddd.com",
          subject:  "Testing out from ACTIONMAILER4",
          bcc:  s_email
        )
      end
    end

    def testemailpubmethod(email)
      begin
      e=TEST_CLASS_email.sendemail(email)
      if e.present?
        e.deliver_now 
      end
      rescue Exception => exception
        puts "Email:Exception Message: #{exception.message}" 
        puts "Error sending the email #{exception.backtrace.join("\n")}"
      end
    end

    testemailpubmethod("eeee@ffff.com")    


Now create the template files in the following subdirectory.
============================================================
./test_class_email/sendemail.text.erb
=====================================
    This is a text email from <%= @var %>
    -Have fun using Actionmailer4 :)
```